# Maximising Internet explorer Window

Tags: javascript

When a pop up occurs,i want the parent window to get maximised if it is less than the maximum size and also get the focus to itself(As Parent).

To explain the scenario in detail,

1. When i receive some e-mail notification i get a pop-up
   window(Prompt/New-Window) in IE.At such instant,is there a method to find out that event and make a call to a function to maximise the screen and gain focus.
2. Also,At the time when i receive the notification i might not be working on the same window,and, i might be on some other folder/document/explorer.

Comment: 1. Do NOT do this with a public website. 2. What have you tried so far? E.g., have you tried using `window.focus();` and `window.resizeTo()`?

Comment: @nnnnnn Yes,i know that we need to use these functions as a seperate method call,but i am searching for the event on the pop up action/prompt which should call the above function.

Comment: What is a "pop up action/prompt"? Is that something you've coded?

Comment: @nnnnnn It is the default pop up like in Java Scrript.An error/warning/alert window

Comment: The only sites I've ever seen that maximise the browser window are spammy advertising sites. It's a very good way to make people want to leave your site and never come back.

Comment: @Hariharan - OK, please clarify: is this a web page that you control? Is it code you've written that pops up the alert? If it is, just before the alert try `window.focus();` or some variation thereon. If it is not your web page I suspect the answer is that you can't do what you want.